# Why am I getting syntax checking failed everytime I parse an assignment statement using javacc tool?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, io, javacc

I have made a `AssignStatement` class and I am trying to pass the string using javacc

The assignment statement is of the form : `a=b+c*d`

Here is the source code

```
PARSER_BEGIN(AssignStatement)

public class AssignStatement
{      

  public static void main(String s[])
  {
   try
     {
       AssignStatement as=new AssignStatement(System.in);
       as.StartSymbol();
       System.out.println("Syntax checking successfully");
     }

  catch(Throwable e)
     {
      System.out.println("Syntex checking failed"+e.getMessage());
     }
  }
}

PARSER_END(AssignStatement)

   SKIP: {"" | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }
   TOKEN:{ "(" | ")" | "+" | "*" | ":="| <NUM: (["0"-"9"])+> | <ID:(["0"-"9"])+>
         }

   void StartSymbol(): {}
  { 
    (AStmt())*<EOF>
  }

  void AStmt(): {}
 { 
  LOOKAHEAD(2) <ID> "=" AStmt() 
  | Term() ("+" Term())*
 }

  void Term(): {}
 {
  Factor() ("*" Factor())*
 } 

  void Factor(): {}
 {
    <NUM> 
  | <ID> 
  | "(" AStmt() ")"
 }
```

The output I got after I did `java AssignStatement`

```
"a=10+20*30" or a=10+20*30
```

> Syntax checking failed error: Bailing out of infinite loop caused by repeated empty string matches at line 1, column 1.

From my point of you there can be 2 possibilities

1. I am taking input from user wrong [in that case please suggest and also how to take input from a file
2. My grammar is wrong. Please suggest

Please guide if anyone can?

Comment: Turn on the DEBUG_TOKEN_MANAGER option when the token manager is behaving in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the line

```
SKIP: {"" | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }
```

This says that you want to skip any 0 length strings. The problem is that having found such a token, the lexer removes 0 characters from the input, and then, of course, it finds the same 0 length token and so on *ad infinitum*.

Perhaps you meant

```
SKIP: {" " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }
```

Now, on input "a=10+20*30", no regular expression will match and you will get a TokenManagerError.

Matching the empty string has its (rare) uses. This is not one of them.

A second problem is with the rule

```
TOKEN:{ ... <NUM: (["0"-"9"])+> | <ID:(["0"-"9"])+> }
```

Since the definition of ID is the same as the definition of  NUM, it will never succeed. Perhaps you want something like

```
TOKEN:{ ... <NUM: (["0"-"9"])+> | <ID:(["a"-"z"])+> }
```

If you do that you won't get the TokenManagerError on the input "a=10+20*30".

Comment: I made the following corrections as  u told and now i am getting the following errors which i am not able to find out in my AssignStatement.jj file After i typed this :C:\javaccprog\AssignStatement>java AssignStatement
"a=10+20*30"  Error Came 
Syntex checking failedLexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "\"" (34)
, after : ""

Comment: Turn on the option to debug the token manager.  If you can't solve it that way, feel free to post a new question with full details.